# How to state a "direct" has_many association between two models through a third model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1 and I would like to implement a "direct" `has_many` association between `Article` and `CommentRequest` in the following case:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment_associations
  has_many :comments, :through => :comment_associations
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_associations
  has_many :articles, :through => :article_associations

  has_many :comment_request_associations
  has_many :comment_requests, :through => :comment_request_associations
end

class CommentRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment_associations
  has_many :comments, :through => :comment_associations
end
```

That is, I would like to state a `has_many` association in both `Article` and `CommentRequest` in order to make it possible to run code as-like the following:

```
@article.comment_requests
@comment_request.articles
```

If it is possible, how to make that?

Comment: Did you read Rails Guides? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment_associations
  has_many :comments, :through => :comment_associations
  has_many :comment_requests, :through => :comments
end
```

since rails allows you to nest `has_many :through` relationships

and similarly

```
class CommentRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment_associations
  has_many :comments, :through => :comment_associations
  has_many :articles, :through => :comments
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, what I should state in the `CommentRequest` model so to run `@comment_request.articles`?

Comment: It's basically the same thing